# I want to show only selected data from json data received from an api

Tags: php, json

I am trying to build a web app using "api.hypixel.net" hypixel API . I am getting all data in json format and able to print it but want to print only selected data using product name.

`

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$url = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);


if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
    echo $e;
}
else {
    $decoded = json_decode($resp);


    print_r($decoded);
    
    
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php how to parse Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46295250/php-how-to-parse-json)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php parse json data from google directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239202/php-parse-json-data-from-google-directions)